# html2pdf.js on leaflet map missing some svgs or images

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, leaflet, html2pdf

Images that have styles that are related to coordinates of them in the map don't show in the generated PDF. All of them have a `transform: translate3d(233px, 283px, 0px);` style. If I delete the style they show up in the PDF but in a wrong place. I think html2pdf has a problem with these styles.

When I use `ctrl+p` in Chrome it all works fine but the problem is that I can't get the blob of the map and send it to the server.

I tried to use another style instead of `transform: translate3d()` but it still didn't work. My packages are all the latest version. What else can i do?

Here's my implementation:

```js
async MakePdf () {

      this.$q.loading.show({
        spinner: QSpinnerPie,
        color: 'indigo-10',
        delay: 400 // ms
      })

      const element = await document.getElementById('notebook-convert')

      const opt = {
        filename: 'File.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { scale: 2, useCORS: true }, 
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'A3', orientation: 
        this.orientation.value }
      }

      html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save()
      const blob = await 
      html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).toPdf().output('blob')
      return blob
    },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to be more readable. Please make a greater effort to use proper grammar in the future, as outlined in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Proofread%20before%20posting!) guide.